# Mutating Operator Error After Changing to Swift 3, Issue Researched, but can't solve

Tags: swift3, operator-keyword, xcode8, mutable

I am getting a "left side of mutating operator isn't mutable "..<" returns immutable value" error

I read the other post regarding mutating values but I can't figure out how those solutions apply.

Code (and comments):

```
 //populate array of 3 random numbers using correct answer and 2 incorrect choices

 func insertIntoArray3(_ randomNumber: Int) -> Int {
for intJ in 0 ..< 2 += 1{

    if arrayIndex != 3 {
        checkIfExists(randomNumber)
        if ifExists {
            let randomNumber = 1 + random() % 10
            insertIntoArray3(randomNumber)
        } else {
            array3[arrayIndex] = (randomNumber)
            arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1
        }
    }

}
return randomNumber
}
```

Revised Code:

```
 //populate array of 3 random numbers using correct answer and 2 incorrect choices
func insertIntoArray3(_ randomNumber: Int) -> Int {

    for _ in 0 ..< 2 + 1{

        if arrayIndex != 3 {
            checkIfExists(randomNumber)
            if ifExists {
                let randomNumber = 1 + arc4random() % 10
                insertIntoArray3(Int(randomNumber))
            } else {
                array3[arrayIndex] = (randomNumber)
                arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1
            }
        }

    }
    return randomNumber
}
```

Thank you!

I'm getting the same error here too....

```
//this function populates an array of the 40 image names

func populateAllImagesArray() {
for  intIA in 1 ..< 11 += 1 {

    tempImageName = ("\(intIA)")
    imageArray.append(tempImageName)

    tempImageName = ("\(intIA)a")
    imageArray.append(tempImageName)

    tempImageName = ("\(intIA)b")
    imageArray.append(tempImageName)

    tempImageName = ("\(intIA)c")
    imageArray.append(tempImageName)
}

//println("imageArray: \(imageArray) ")
//println(imageArray.count)
}
```

Revised:

```
 //this function populates an array of the 40 image names
func populateAllImagesArray() {

    for  intIA in 1 ..< 11 + 1 {

        tempImageName = ("\(intIA)")
        imageArray.append(tempImageName)

        tempImageName = ("\(intIA)a")
        imageArray.append(tempImageName)

        tempImageName = ("\(intIA)b")
        imageArray.append(tempImageName)

        tempImageName = ("\(intIA)c")
        imageArray.append(tempImageName)
    }

    //println("imageArray: \(imageArray) ")
    //println(imageArray.count)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `for  intIA in 1 ..< 11 += 1 ` here `+=1` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line that's throwing the error is:

```
for intJ in 0 ..< 2 += 1{
```

The `+=` operator is a *mutating operator*, meaning that it tells Swift to take whatever is on the left side of it and *change it*, in this case by adding whatever is on the right.

So what you're telling Swift here is, take `0 ..< 2` and change it into `(0 ..< 2) + 1`. This throws an error because the `..<` operator returns a range which is *immutable* - once created, it can't be changed.

Even if you could mutate a range, that's probably not what you want to do. From the context it looks like maybe you want to add 1 to the right side, in which case you'd just get rid of the `=`:

```
for intJ in 0 ..< 2 + 1{
```

This just turns the right side into 3, so the loop goes [0, 1, 2].

Or maybe you're just trying to tell it to increment by 1 every time, like the `i += 1` in a standard C-style for loop. If that's the case you don't need it here. Indexing by 1 is the default behavior, so you can leave out the whole `+= 1` bit:

```
for intJ in 0 ..< 2 {
```

Or if you need to increment by something other than 1, you can use the [Strideable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/strideable), which looks like:

```
for intJ in stride(from: min, to: max, by: increment) {
```

Just replace `min`, `max` and `increment` with the appropriate numbers.

Comment: Thank you! revised code:  
    func insertIntoArray3(_ randomNumber: Int) -> Int {
        
        for _ in 0 ..< 2 + 1{
            
            if arrayIndex != 3 {
                checkIfExists(randomNumber)
                if ifExists {
                    let randomNumber = 1 + arc4random() % 10
                    insertIntoArray3(Int(randomNumber))
                } else {
                    array3[arrayIndex] = (randomNumber)
                    arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1
                }
            }
            
        }
        return randomNumber
    }

Answer (score 1):

add `var` in for loop, will make left variable mutable

```
for var intIA in 1 ..< 11 {

    intIA = intIA+3
    print("\(intIA)")
}
```

And in your snippet, `for intIA in 1 ..< 11 += 1` here `+=1` is incorrect.

Comment: Will try that as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's a real-world example using a common `setUpTable` function.

Swift 2: C-Style Loop

```
func setupTable() {
    tableView.setNumberOfRows(nameArray.count, withRowType: "ContactListCell")    
    for i in 0 ..< nameArray.count += 1 {
        let cell = tableView.rowController(at: Int(i)) as? ContactListCell
        let nameText = nameArray[i]
        cell!.nameLabel.setText(nameText)
    }
}
```

> Error: left side of mutating operator isn't mutable "..<" returns immutable value

Swift 3 Fix: When we setup tables we are iterating through cell rows i.e. **ContactListCell** so that we can display them in the table. `for i in 0 ..< nameArray.count` already indexes by 1 therefore we don't need the C-style `+= 1` syntax.

```
for i in 0 ..< nameArray.count {}
```