# Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable '..<' returns immutable value

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I developed an app in Swift 2.0 years ago, it ran smoothly. Today I updated the code to 3.0 (and later would to 4.0) but I am getting an issue saying "Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable '..<' returns immutable value" I can't seem to solve.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388873/mutating-operator-error-after-changing-to-swift-3-issue-researched-but-cant-s) of removing the '=' from '+=' did not work for me, hope someone can help me get this resolved.

```
for i: CGFloat in 0  ..< self.frame.size.width / (groundTexture.size().width) += 1 {
```

The full code looks like this:

```
func moveGroundFunc(_ duration: TimeInterval, piece: SKSpriteNode) {
    let groundMovingLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: duration)

    let resetGround = SKAction.moveBy(x: -groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)

    let groundMovingLeftForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([groundMovingLeft, resetGround]))

    for i: CGFloat in 0  ..< self.frame.size.width / (groundTexture.size().width) += 1 {
        piece.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: groundPiece.size.height)
        piece.position = CGPoint(x: i * piece.size.width, y: piece.size.height - 75)
    }
```

Comment: Just split it into two lines; one that calculates the end of the range and assigns it to a constant. Then use that in the loop

Comment: @Paulw11, would you be able to paste the code somewhere? I haven't written code in a while and can't understand your comment, though I'm sure it's simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to mutate the result of an expression (using `+= 1`); this isn't possible since anonymous results are constants and therefore immutable.

I am not sure why changing the `+= 1` to `+1` didn't work, but you can simply split it into two lines.  If you change the range operator from `..<` to `...` you can get rid of the `+1` as well.

Your other problem is that you can't use a range with `CGFloat` - You need to use a type that implements `SignedInteger`.  An Integer division may not give you the same result.  If it doesn't then you could change the loop to use incrementing rather than a range.

```
let width = Int(self.frame.size.width / groundTexture.size().width)

for i in 0...width {
    piece.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: groundPiece.size.height)
    piece.position = CGPoint(x: i * piece.size.width, y: piece.size.height - 75)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. The issue I get now is "Binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'" When I use my old code and just remove the = it gives the same message except it says '..<' instead of '...' with the same error.

Comment: On which line?  What is `GroundTexture.size()` returning?  You will need to identify which value is the `Int` and use `CGFloat()` around it.

Comment: GroundTexture.size() is fine, the error shows up in the first line where we have for i: CGFloat in 0...width

Comment: See my update; You need to use an `Int`, which may not give the same result

Comment: Thanks, It worked! I just had to change the 0...width to 0 ..< width, but everything else was perfect.